# Нужна помощь: нужно подключить драйвер JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Здравствуйте.
Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему: нужно подключить драйвер *JDBC* - хочу настроить соединение с *MySQL* в *Java*. Скачал коннектор здесь https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ и не понимаю (английский очень слабый) куда нужно этот файл вставить, как его подключить и что такое *CLASSPATH* и как его прописать. Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться.

Код выглядит так:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

// JDBC URL, username and password of MySQL server
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_connect";
private static final String user = "root";
private static final String password = "";

// JDBC variables for opening and managing connection
private static Connection con;
private static Statement stmt;
private static ResultSet rs;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String query = "select count(*) from books";

    try {
        // opening database connection to MySQL server
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        // getting Statement object to execute query
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        // executing SELECT query
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            int count = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("Total number of books in the table : " + count);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //close connection ,stmt and resultset here
        try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
        try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
        try { rs.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
    }
}

}
```

Стоит *IDEA Intelij*, при запуске программы в консоле выдает: `No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_connect`

База данных создана, *Java* настроена разумеется.

Comment: Напишите, что уже сделали. Покажите код. Не понятно, у Вас база данных уже готова или нет. Java настроена или нет. Напишите подробнее, либо возможно Ваш вопрос закроют.

Answer (score 2):

Руководство для работы с MySQL:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже разобрался :) Добавил в среде разработки драйвер и все заработало.

Comment: я потратил 2 дня на поиски решения, но только ваш комментарий к ответу мне помог. поставил бы хоть 100 лайков за него. ни один видеоблогер, ни один человек не помог так как вы. вот полная последовательность действий: Нажать на кнопку настройки проекта
Выбрать "Project Structure"
Далее в интерфейсе открывшегося окна выбрать "Moduls" добавить необходимый драйвер нажав "+".