# Почему не происходит подключения к MySql с помощью JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, jdbc, timeout

Всем доброго время суток. Скажите пожалуйста в чём может заключаться проблема при подключении к бд через JDBC? И возможно ли исправить? Пытался в интернете поискать решения ([например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683949/connection-timeout-for-drivermanager-getconnection)), но интересного не чего нет.

**Вот то что я сделал** :

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mybd?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
private static final String user = "root";
private static final String password = "welcome";

private static Connection con;

public static void connecttodb() {

        // opening database connection to MySQL server
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

}
```

**Собственно сама ошибка** (вылазит секунд через 5 после вызова команды) :

> Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3
>   times. Giving up.

... чуть дальше ...

> CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required

**UPD** (После первого решения) :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD** :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD** :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а клиентом из командной строки удается подключиться?

Comment: `root/welcome` это сильно :)

Comment: вы точно ту библиотеку подключили? в логах вижу `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: @SeniorAutomator вроде-бы, выбрал ту библиотеку которая предлагается свежаком на офф сайте.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy должны быть `java.sql.Statement` and `java.sql.Connection`. у вас не так. исправьте и все заработает

Comment: @SeniorAutomator вроде-бы помогло, но появилась новая ошибка. Что же за горе такое, а не БД.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy создайте новый вопрос с описанием, стректрейсом

Comment: Может поможет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607102/Нужна-помощь-нужно-подключить-драйвер-jdbc/607118?noredirect=1#comment830171_607118

Comment: Поменяйте драйвер на com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver. И попробуйте поменять mysql-connector-оjava на более свежий - сейчас версия 8.0.13 если я не ошибаюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mybd?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
private static final String user = "root";
private static final String password = "welcome";

private static Connection con;

public static void connecttodb() {
        // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Setup the connection with the DB
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

}
```

Comment: не помогает :(

P.S. скрин ошибки в теме обновил

Comment: Он у Вас не видеть базу, попробуйте  через консоль или через phpmyadmin зайти.

Answer (score 0):

Вы используйте какой-то другую библиотеку или класс, а должны быть `java.sql.Statement` and `java.sql.Connection`.

Исправьте и все заработает